Optimizing Mouse Movement Functionality During Screen Sharing
I am currently developing a screen-sharing application similar to Anydesk or TeamView using Electron, React, NodeJS (signalling sever) and RobotJS (for simulating mouse move events).
I have used WebRTC data channels for transmitting mouse events and implemented debouncing to optimize the continuous transmission of events. These changes improved the speed of mouse movements but they are still not as fast as those in AnyDesk or TeamViewer.
Initially, I used Socket.io (WebSocket) to transmit the mouse movement events. However, since WebSocket is a bit slower, I switched to WebRTC data channels to share the mouse events.
I have also used debouncing to optimize the continuous transmitting events. These changes made the mouse movements a bit faster, but still not as fast as compared to AnyDesk or TeamViewer.
Is there any other way to make the mouse movement events as fast as those in AnyDesk or TeamViewer?
Controlling PC:
const handleMouseMove = (e: React.MouseEvent < HTMLDivElement > ) => {
  if (connectionState === "connected" && videoRef.current && videoRects) {
    const relativeX = (e.clientX - videoRects.left) / videoRects.width;
    const relativeY = (e.clientY - videoRects.top) / videoRects.height;

    if (dataChannel.current) {
      const message = JSON.stringify({
        type: 'mouse-move',
        payload: {
          x: relativeX,
          y: relativeY,
        }
      });

      if (debounceTimeout.current) {
        clearTimeout(debounceTimeout.current);
      }

      debounceTimeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
        dataChannel.current!.send(message);
        debounceTimeout.current = null;
      }, 14); // Adjust the delay as needed
    }
  }
};

Remote PC:
ipcMain.on('mouse-move', (_, data) => {
  try {
    console.time("Mouse move")
    const {
      x,
      y
    } = data;

    const adjustedX = Math.round(x * screenWidth) + nativeOrigin.x;
    const adjustedY = Math.round(y * screenHeight) + nativeOrigin.y;

    robot.moveMouse(adjustedX, adjustedY);
    console.timeEnd("Mouse move")
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Mouse Move error: ", e);
  }
});

I have also used console.time() to check how much time the
robot.moveMouse() function takes, which turned out to be 10ms.

Even I am looking for a similar solution
